# Checkstyle custom check access property value?

Tags: properties, checkstyle

Can someone tell me or point me to some documentation regarding Checkstyle custom checks and accessing property values?

My custom class needs to obtain a regex file the users supply.  Can they supply this file as a property in the Checkstyle .xml config file?  If so, how does my custom Check class read the value of the property?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way around this problem.  Just set a java Property using `-Dpropertyname=propertyvalue`, then in the custom class get the property value.